# JSON.Net Deserialze in C# - Not All Code Paths Return a Value

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I'm fairly new to using JSON within an application, and doing some simple programming to become better versed in how to interpret and use JSON data. I have a class `Account` with a method `getAccount`, which should be using RestSharp to call for a JSON array which returns this:

`[{"account_id":"1"}]`

What I am trying to do is have JSON.Net serialize the JSON response and pull the data into a string, to use later.

Here is what I have:

```
class Account
{
    public string account_id {get; set;}

    public Account getAccount(String username, String password)
    {

            var client = new RestClient("http://www.myapiurl.com/api/");
            var request = new RestRequest("login.php?username={username}&password={password}, Method.POST");
            request.AddParameter("username", username);
            request.AddParameter("password", password);
            RestResponse response = (RestResponse)(client.Execute(request));

            Account account = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Account>(response.ToString());
            account_id = account.account_id.ToString();

    }
}
```

}

The error message I am getting in VS2013 is:

DataLogic.Account.getAccount(string, string) not all code paths return a value

I'm not sure where I'm missing code to make sure the method always returns a value, or how to compensate for that.

Any guidance/explanation would be greatly appreciated, or suggestions on how to better approach this concept.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not returning anything. You have to return account.

Comment: I don't see any return statement in the method

Comment: The method signature promises that it will `return` an `Account`, but the method fails to do so.  The error message is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return a value from your method:

```
return account;
```

The return type of your method is described in the method definition:

```
public Account getAccount(String username, String password)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error has nothing to do with JSON.Net or deserialization. You are not returning the object.

Just add the following line at the end of your method.

```
return account;
```

Your method signature states that the method will return an object of type `Account`

```
public Account getAccount(String username, String password)
       ^^^^^^^
      //return type
```

and your method code is missing the the return statement, Hence the error.